# How can i store the unexpected errors coming in server console to a seperate log file using my custom logger

Tags: flask, logging, python-logging

I have developed an application and deployed into server, I have created a custom logging using the dictconfig, where it will logs whatever the logs I want to print, but if any unexpected error comes, It is not being seen in the log file, I am only able to see them by

```
journalctl -u myapp.service
```

But I want to capture those logs and store them into file using my custom logger

My logging config is

```
class loggingConfig():

    def filter_maker(level):
        level = getattr(logging, level)

        def filter(record):
            return record.levelno <= level
        return filter
    LOGGINGCONFIG='''
    {
        "version":1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": false,
        "formatters": {
            "simple":{
                "format":"%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s"
            }
        },
        "filters":  {
                    "info_and_debug": {
                            "()":"config.loggingConfig.filter_maker",
                            "level":"INFO"
                    }
        },
        "handlers": {
                    "stHand":{
                        "class":"logging.StreamHandler",
                        "formatter":"simple",
                        "level":"DEBUG",
                        "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
                    },
                    "infoHand": {
                        "class":"logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
                        "level":"DEBUG",
                        "formatter":"simple",
                        "filename":"/home/chandra/rnd/projects/FaceauthenticationSDK/logs/info.log",
                        "when":"D",
                        "interval":1,
                        "filters":["info_and_debug"]
                    },
                    "errHand": {
                        "class":"logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
                        "level":"ERROR",
                        "formatter":"simple",
                        "filename":"/home/chandra/rnd/projects/FaceauthenticationSDK/logs/error.log",
                        "when":"D",
                        "interval":1
                    }
        },
        "root":{
                "level":"DEBUG",
                "handlers":[
                            "stHand",
                            "infoHand",
                            "errHand"
                ]
                }
    }
    '''
```